# Optimizing a conversion template (using external XML), with xsl:call-template

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

At this moment I already got an XSLT (named myLookupTable.xslt from now on) that can be included into other XSLT files to be able to do some code conversions. This myLookupTable.xslt is a named template to be used by everyone how writes XSLT files and wants to use this. So I really need to stick to this `xsl:call-template` as done now.

The XSLT is working fine at the moment, but with really big XML files that contains the conversions it taking more time and I am looking into howto optimize things.

For example:

- Is it better to use `xsl:key`? If so, how will I do this within the `xsl:call-template`?
- Any other structure changes so I still be able to stick to the `xsl:call-template`?
- If it is better to get rid of the `xsl:call-template`, why should I do it and how can I make the implementation of this for others as easy as it can be?

I have read an artcile about [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), I get the point, but are not quite sure howto implement this into this `xsl:call-template` example.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

**Input XML example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pref:data xmlns:pref="http://example.org/uri/data">
    <pref:PackageGroup>
        <pref:sendPackage>BX</pref:sendPackage>
        <pref:sendRelation>66778899</pref:sendRelation>
    </pref:PackageGroup>
    <pref:TypeGroup>
        <pref:sendType>80</pref:sendType>
        <pref:sendRelation>88996677</pref:sendRelation>
    </pref:TypeGroup>
</pref:data>
```

**XSLT for conversion on the input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pref="http://example.org/uri/data">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Include lookup table XSLT and add variable to the lookup table xml -->
    <xsl:include href="myLookupTable.xslt"/>
    <xsl:variable name="myLookupTableFile">myLookupTable.xml</xsl:variable>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Translate packageCode -->
    <xsl:template match="pref:sendPackage">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="myLookup">
                <xsl:with-param name="file"><xsl:value-of select="$myLookupTableFile" /></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="direction">in</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="function">filter</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="table">packageCode</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="relation"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::pref:sendRelation"/></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Translate type -->
    <xsl:template match="pref:sendType">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="myLookup">
                <xsl:with-param name="file"><xsl:value-of select="$myLookupTableFile" /></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="direction">in</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="function">filter</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="table">type</xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="relation"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::pref:sendRelation"/></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT that contains the xsl:call-template**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:conv="http://example.org/uri/lookuptable">
    <xsl:template name="myLookup">
        <xsl:param name="file"/><!-- Name of the conversion XML file -->
        <xsl:param name="direction"/><!-- 'in' ('directionIncoming' element is used) or 'out' ('directionOutgoing' element is used) -->
        <xsl:param name="function"/><!-- 'copy', 'copy+', 'filter', 'filter+' -->
        <xsl:param name="table"/><!-- Name of the lookup table to use for conversion (see 'name' attribute of 'translateCode' element) -->
        <xsl:param name="relation"/><!-- Relation number to use for conversion (see 'relation' attribute of 'translateValue' element) -->
        <xsl:param name="value"/><!-- Value to convert -->
        <xsl:variable name="fallbackRelation">0</xsl:variable>

        <!-- Step 1: convert input value -->
        <xsl:variable name="result1">
            <xsl:call-template name="convert">
                <xsl:with-param name="file" select="$file"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="direction" select="$direction"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="function" select="$function"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="table" select="$table"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="relation" select="$relation"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Step 2: if result is empty and function name ends with '+' convert again using fallback relation number -->
        <xsl:variable name="result2">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($result1)=0 and ends-with($function,'+') and $relation!='0'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="convert">
                        <xsl:with-param name="file" select="$file"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="direction" select="$direction"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="function" select="$function"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="table" select="$table"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="relation" select="$fallbackRelation"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$value"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$result1"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Step 3: if result is still empty and function name starts with 'copy' use original input value as output result -->
        <xsl:variable name="result3">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($result2)=0 and starts-with($function,'copy')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$result2"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Step 4: final conversion result -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$result3"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template for actual conversion using external conversion XML file. -->
    <xsl:template name="convert">
        <xsl:param name="file"/>
        <xsl:param name="direction"/>
        <xsl:param name="function"/>
        <xsl:param name="table"/>
        <xsl:param name="relation"/>
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$direction='in'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="document($file)/conv:myLookupTable/conv:table[@name=$table]/conv:directionIncoming/conv:translateCode[@name=$value]/conv:translateValue[@relation=$relation]/text()"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document($file)/conv:myLookupTable/conv:table[@name=$table]/conv:directionOutgoing/conv:translateCode[@name=$value]/conv:translateValue[@relation=$relation]/text()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML that can be used to lookup the code conversions**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myLookupTable xmlns="http://example.org/uri/lookuptable">
    <table name="packageCode">
        <directionIncoming>
            <translateCode name="BX">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">GH</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="66778899">LK</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="88996677">LK</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
            <translateCode name="PL">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">BT</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="66778899">LK</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="88996677">LK</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
        </directionIncoming>
        <directionOutgoing>
            <translateCode name="LK">
                <translateValue relation="66778899">BX</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="88996677">BX</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
            <translateCode name="BT">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">PL</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
            <translateCode name="GH">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">PL</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
        </directionOutgoing>
    </table>
    <table name="type">
        <directionIncoming>
            <translateCode name="10">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">20</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="66778899">30</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="88996677">30</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
            <translateCode name="80">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">90</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="66778899">30</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="88996677">30</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
        </directionIncoming>
        <directionOutgoing>
            <translateCode name="30">
                <translateValue relation="66778899">10</translateValue>
                <translateValue relation="88996677">10</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
            <translateCode name="90">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">80</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
            <translateCode name="20">
                <translateValue relation="99887766">80</translateValue>
            </translateCode>
        </directionOutgoing>
    </table>
</myLookupTable>
```

**EDIT**

When I apply Martin Honnen his solution as described below and I change my input XML from `<pref:sendPackage>BX</pref:sendPackage>` to `<pref:sendPackage>XX</pref:sendPackage>` (key lookup will return nothing) and I execute the transform in Altova XML Spy I get the error:

[image: Error from Altova XMLSpy]

The code looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('relationKey', $relation, key('incomingKey', $value, key('tableKey', $table, document($file))))/text()" />
```

Even if I do a `xsl:if` around it, the test passes (strange enough), but the `xsl:value-of select` still gives the same error:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(key('k3', $relation, key('k2', $value, key('k1', $table, document($file))))/text()) != ''">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('k3', $relation, key('k2', $value, key('k1', $table, document($file))))/text()" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Using `xsl:key` for large input files can definitely be very helpful. I had cases with input files in the range of 800-1000 MegaBytes in which I experienced a speedup of factor 10-100. I think one of the restrictions may be that the key definition has to be a child of the XSLT stylesheet tag. This would require you to _unhide_ some of the details of the structure of your XML mapping files. On the other hand, probably some of the parameters to `myLookup` may not be necessary anymore since they are implicitly given in the key definition. Instead you will have to pass the key name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use keys to replace expressions like `document($file)/conv:myLookupTable/conv:table[@name=$table]` e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="conv:myLookupTable/conv:table" use="@name"/>
```

allows you to rewrite

```
document($file)/conv:myLookupTable/conv:table[@name=$table]
```

as

```
key('k1', $table, document($file))
```

Now for `conv:directionIncoming/conv:translateCode[@name=$value]` you define

```
<xsl:key name="k2" match="conv:directionIncoming/conv:translateCode" use="@name"/>
```

and then replace

```
document($file)/conv:myLookupTable/conv:table[@name=$table]/conv:directionIncoming/conv:translateCode[@name=$value]
```

with

```
  key('k2', $value, key('k1', $table, document($file)))
```

and finally for

```
document($file)/conv:myLookupTable/conv:table[@name=$table]/conv:directionIncoming/conv:translateCode[@name=$value]/conv:translateValue[@relation=$relation]
```

you would use

```
<xsl:key name="k3" match="conv:translateCode/conv:translateValue" use="@relation"/>
```

and

```
key('k3', $relation, key('k2', $value, key('k1', $table, document($file))))
```

I would also suggest to use `<xsl:with-param name="param-name" select="foo"/>` instead of `<xsl:with-param name="param-name"><xsl:value-of select="foo"/></xsl:with-param>` as much as possible and to use `<xsl:variable name="var-name" select="foo"/>` instead of `<xsl:variable name="var-name"><xsl:value-of select="foo"/></xsl:variable>`. That should be more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the complete and extended answer. Did not know that using the `select` attribute in `xsl:with-param` and `xsl:variable` would be more efficient also. Thanks very much

Comment: How about handling lookups that do not exist in the key index? For example in the input XML change `<pref:sendPackage>BX</pref:sendPackage>` to `<pref:sendPackage>XX</pref:sendPackage>`

Comment: @MarkVeenstra, does the key based look up give a different result than your previous code if a value does not exist? Much like you can check e.g. `<xsl:if test="document($file)/conv:myLookupTable/conv:table[@name=$table]">...</xsl:if>` you can check `<xsl:if test="key('k1', $table, document($file))">...</xsl:if>` if you need or want that. But I don't see you doing such checks.

Comment: I updated the question with the error I am getting. I also tried to do a `xsl:if` in front of it. But I still receive the error, but the test is passing strange enough. I do use the same input and conversion XML as posted in this question.

Comment: Looks like i should test all the keys seperatly as follows: `<xsl:if test="normalize-space(key('tableKey', $table, document($file))) != '' and normalize-space(key('incomingKey', $value, key('tableKey', $table, document($file)))) != '' and normalize-space(key('relationKey', $relation, key('incomingKey', $value, key('tableKey', $table, document($file))))) != ''">`. When I do this the error is gone and it will return an empty node, which would be correct.